# MySQL: How to convert Char into Date?

Tags: mysql

I want to compare two fields with the same datatype which is char(8) wherein the input is for DATE.

I used

```
select * from TABLE where DateChar1 <> DateChar2;
```

However, upon checking the said fields they have a different input..

```
DateChar1 = '03102015'

DateChar2 = '20150310'
```

I already tried but returns NULL.

```
DATE_FORMAT(DateChar1 , "%d/%l/%Y") as DateChar1 
DATE_FORMAT(DateChar1 , '%Y, %d %m') as DateChar1
DATE_FORMAT(DateChar2 , '%Y, %d %m') as DateChar2 
DATE_FORMAT(DateChar2 , '%Y, %d %m') as DateChar2 
DATE(DateChar1 ) as (DateChar1 
DATE(DateChar2 ) as DateChar2
```

thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `STR_TO_DATE()` function

```
select * from TABLE
where STR_TO_DATE(DateChar1,'%d%m%Y') <> STR_TO_DATE(DateChar2,'%Y%m%d');
```

> DateChar1 = '03102015' (I supposed your date ddmmyyyy)
>
> DateChar2 = '20150310' (I supposed your date yyyymmdd)

Comment: is there any link to a list of the `%.` operators ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format this is the link where you see all formate of date

Comment: This link is about `str_to_date()` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: Well, apparently that all what's out there, I looked myself and that's all what I found... Thanks <3

Comment: @fLen if it is work why are you not accept answer because it appreciate me to help other.

Answer (score 1):

Try mysql function `STR_TO_DATE()`

```
select * from TABLE where STR_TO_DATE(DateChar1,  '%d/%m/%Y' ) <> STR_TO_DATE(DateChar2,  '%d/%m/%Y' );
```

Answer (score 1):

use mysql function `STR_TO_DATE()`
example :`SELECT STR_TO_DATE('21,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y');`